# IF formula with cell value returned

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am creating a spreadsheet where it shows a total number. For example A5 May show 36, but B5 May show 22. I need to enter a formula that if the number is over 30, it shows 30 however if it's under 30 to display the numbers in the cell (B5 in this example). I've managed the first bit but can't get the second - can anyone help?
Thank you!

I have tried:

```
=IF(A5>30,"30"),IF(A5<30,"A5")
```

Comment: Side note: `"` denotes text. If you want a number, don't use quotes: `30`, not `"30"`. If you want a cell reference, don't use quotes: `B5` not `"B5"` (presumably `"A5"` is a typo).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just get a #VALUE! without using "".

Comment: `=IF(A5>30,30,IF(A5<30,B5,"something else"))`

Comment: Perfect worked thanks so much!!

Comment: Or this: =IF(A5>30,30,B5), but you might consider =IF(A5>=30,30,B5) as you don't specify what to do when the value is **exactly** 30.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, should be:

```
=IF(A5>30,30, A5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your logic correctly:

`=IF(А5>=30,30,B5)`

If cell A5 is equal to or greater than 30, this formula will return 30. Anything less than 30 will return value from B5.

Comment: For example: A5 = 36, B5 = 22. Is A6 greater than 30 ? Yes, it is. Then, return 22 from B5.